# android: Recyclerview for Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview

I have successfully followed the tutorial on `RecyclerView` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

but I was wondering if I could build more complex behaviour using `Fragments` inside the `RecyclerView` instead of plain old `Views`.

using fragments can help make a reusable item with complex behaviour that can be placed in other places and can be much more flexible.

Is it possible and if so , how ?

Comment: like the viewpager does ?

Comment: "using fragments can help make a reusable item with complex behaviour that can be placed in other places and can be much more flexible". A `View` can accomplish that way better. Read [Advocating Against Android Fragments](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html).

Comment: @Blackbelt yes, like this.

Comment: @NiekHaarman using a `RecyclerView` all of the controlling of the view is contained inside `onBindViewHolder`. so if you want to put the view anywhere else , you would need to re-program it. in other words , it's not reusable. moreover , I'm using `Android Annotations` and I can build stuff very easlly in fragments instead of standard views.

Comment: Move the `View` controlling. For example, in a dedicated `Presenter` (as shown in earlier linked article).

Comment: hmmm... maybe that's what I'm looking for. I will investigate further , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

RecyclerView is for a view that repeats a lot with different data, it's designed for use in long scrolly lists because inflating (constructing) the View Object takes some effort, so recycling takes the View you just scrolled off the top of the screen, quickly fills it with new data and puts it at the bottom.

I wouldn't have thought using a Fragment like that would work well, whenever you scroll the list it'll need to be re-created and run its various setup methods which will be quite expensive. And if you make it so it doesn't have to do that (setRetainInstance()) then you're not getting anything from it that you wouldn't get from a view.

If that's what you're getting at then yes you could create a Fragment, set it up, mark it as retained and keep a reference to it so it hangs around in memory for you to re-attach to some other parent at some other time. But if you have to change its contents and re-build it then you're not gaining much.